# Tabbar won't hide when pushed into a ViewController inside a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

For the purpose of this question, I'm showing a stripped down version of my view hierarchy. My app contains a `UITabBarController` as the base. Each tab's top most view controller is a navigation controller and it has view controllers embedded in each of them.

[image]

Let's take the first tab.

> UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UITableViewController -> UIViewController

Let's say the `UITableViewController` instance is some sort of a list and the `UIViewController` is the detail view. When the user taps on an item from the list, it takes you to the detail view. And when that happens I have set the `UIViewController`'s `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property to `true` so that the tabbar at the bottom would hide when the user is in the detail view.

[image]   [image]

My app receives push notifications. When tapped on them, it should open directly into the detail view. I can get it to navigate there. But the issue is the tabbar at the bottom is still visible!

[image]

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! TabBarController

    if openingFromPush {
        let firstNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
        let tableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableViewController") as! TableViewController
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        firstNavigationController.viewControllers = [tableViewController, viewController]

        tabBarController.viewControllers?[0] = firstNavigationController
        // tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = true
        window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    } else {
        window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    }

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

I set that same `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property to `true` in the when I instantiate the view controller but that doesn't seem to have any effect. I even tried straight up hiding the tabbar like this `tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = true` but that doesn't do anything at all either.

I can't figure how how to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated.

I attached a sample Xcode project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6wljje1xu9s0g6/TabBarIssue.zip?dl=0) as well if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code for pushing detail view controller:

```
 if openingFromPush {
            let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
            if let nvc = tabBarController.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController {
                nvc.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
            }

            window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
        }
```

You don't need to init navigation view controller and table view controller again its already inside tab bar controller

Comment: As the name suggests, the view controller needed to be *pushed* inside the navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

in storyboard, select "Hide Bottom bar on push"